# how to create a hierarchy table with parent child rows razor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, razor

here is my table snap [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWni2.png)

```
I am creating this table from my model in razor view 

it shows the structure of task and sub-tasks and their subtask ... 
but the problem is it loads sub task and their subtask ... in the same level  when someone clicks on the first column it loads its child under the parent
```

it's loads them and add a table row under the correspondence row
here is my jquery code I want to make it hierarchical like there should be a difference in parent and child level

```
 function showHierarchy(taskId) {

        if ($('.subtaskof_' + taskId).text() == '') {
                       
            $.ajax('/Tasks/sfsubtasks?taskId=' + taskId,   // request url
                {
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data, status, xhr) {// success callback function
                        
                        var subtasklist = JSON.parse(data)
                        console.log(subtasklist);


                        for (i = 0; i < subtasklist.length; i++) {
                          
                            subtask = subtasklist[i];
                            var therowis =  '<tr class=subtaskof_' + taskId + '>'
                                + '<td id="subtaskrow_' + subtask['InstanceId'] + '" align="right">_</td>'                            
                                + '<td>' + subtask['InstanceId'] + '</td>'
                                + '<td>' + subtask["Title"] + '</td>'
                                + '<td>' + subtask["Deliverables"] + '</td>'
                                + '<td>' + subtask["StartDate"] + '</td>'
                                + '<td>' + subtask["Priority"] + '</td>'
                                + '<td>' + subtask["State"] + '</td>'
                                + '<td><a href="/Tasks/Details?taskId=' + subtask['InstanceId'] + '">See Details_subt</a></td>'
                                + '<td><a href="/Tasks/New?projectId=' + subtask['ProjectId'] + '&amp;ParentTaskId=' + subtask['InstanceId'] + '">Add Sub Task_subt</a></td>'
                                + '</tr>'  

                            // Find position to add new subtask row in the Task table
                            $("#my-grid tr").filter(function () {
                                if ($(this).text().indexOf(taskId) >= 0) {
                                    $(this).after(therowis);
                                    issubsubtaskexists = false;
                                    console.log("chield checking for - " + subtask['InstanceId'])
                                    $.ajax('/Tasks/sfsubtasks?taskId=' + subtask['InstanceId'],   // request url
                                    {
                                        async: false,
                                        success: function (data_, status_, xhr_) {
                                            if (data_.length > 0) {
                                                console.log("The data_ is - " + data_);
                                                var subsubtasklist = JSON.parse(data_);
                                                console.log("The subsubtasklist is - " + subsubtasklist)
                                                console.log("lenght for - " + subtask['InstanceId'] + " , is - " + subsubtasklist);

                                                if (subsubtasklist.length > 0) {
                                                    $('#subtaskrow_' + subtask['InstanceId']).html("<b><a style='font-size:25px; padding-left:17px;' id='lnk_" + subtask['InstanceId'] + "' href='#' onclick='showHierarchy(" + subtask['InstanceId'] + ")'> + </a></b>")
                                                    issubsubtaskexists = true;
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                                        });
                                    console.log("The taskId is - "+taskId)
                                    $('#lnk_' + taskId).html('<b>_</b>');
                                    
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                });

        } else {
                // Toggle/removing subtasks
            $('.subtaskof_' + taskId).remove();
            $.ajax('/Tasks/sfsubtasks?taskId=' + taskId,
                {
                    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                        console.log("Checking for child node of taskId - " + taskId);
                        var subsubtasklist = JSON.parse(data)
                        console.log(subsubtasklist);

                        for (i = 0; i < subsubtasklist.length; i++) {
                            $('.subtaskof_' + subsubtasklist[i]['InstanceId']).remove();
                            $.ajax('/Tasks/sfsubtasks?taskId=' + subsubtasklist[i],
                            {
                                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                                    console.log("Checking for child node of taskId - " + taskId);
                                    var subsubtasklist_ = JSON.parse(data)
                                    console.log(subsubtasklist_);
                                    for (j = 0; j < subsubtasklist_.length; j++) {
                                        $('.subtaskof_' + subsubtasklist_[j]['InstanceId']).remove();
                                    }                                    
                                }
                            });                            
                        }
                    }
                });
            
            $('#lnk_' + taskId).html('<b>+</b>');

        }
    }
```

plz let me know what can be done of this table for showing data hierarchically